# The difference between "on the inside of" and "inside of"

Tags: difference

I have come across a sentence with a strange, to me, usage of the word "inside" with the preposition "on". Here goes: " At that time I felt different on the inside of me." why "on" is there? Would it be better without it, like: "I felt different inside of me." If there is any difference between the sentences, tell me it please.

Comment: You don't give the full context, so this question may just be closed soon anyway. But here's a context where there would be a clear semantic distinction... *There's dirt **inside** this bag* would normally be understood to mean *This box **contains** dirt* (probably, a whole ***bagful*** of dirt). But *There's dirt **on the inside of** this bag* would mean a relatively small amount of dirt ***attached to the inner surface*** of the bag.

Comment: Your comment has answered the question, it is now clear to me

Comment: Note that whereas you might just about get away with *At that time I felt different inside*, no native speaker would include anything like ***on the*** or ***of me*** in such a context. Nor would people normally include the word ***inside*** there anyway. It's not like you could "feel different" anywhere ***outside*** yourself (since "feeling" is an internal state) so why include it at all? It's a bit like saying *I think **with my brain** that the usage is both awkward and superfluous*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As often, your last sentence is a prime example of how to use the English language beautifully. And it made me laugh. ^_^

Comment: @Stephie: Thanks! I got my inspiration form *I spy **with my little eye** something beginning with **Why?*** My father's whimsical way of referring to grandchildren who habitually pester him with recursive *But **why**, Grandad?* questions which always and up with him having to admit defeat and sign off with *I don't know. You'll have to ask Grandma.*